# Talend tMap expression comparison

Tags: talend, tmap

I have two connections to different databases. Two dates come from them. Through the tMap component, I want to compare these dates according to the condition that if hive_data > postgres_data or postgres_data is null, run the bash script through the tSystem component.

[image]

[image]

https://prnt.sc/Th3Cr1PoxNaa - job

https://prnt.sc/95HsXYnjzdyB - tMap  expression comparison

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare date, use TalendDate.compareDate() .

The TalendDate.compareDate function in Talend is used to compare two dates and returns an integer value indicating their relative order. The function takes two arguments, both of which should be in the format of java.util.Date objects. The function will return 0 if the two dates are equal, a positive integer if the first date is after the second date, and a negative integer if the first date is before the second date.

Here is an example of how to use the TalendDate.compareDate function in a Talend Job:

```
// Define two date variables
java.util.Date date1 = TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "2022-01-01");
java.util.Date date2 = TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "2022-12-31");

// Compare the two dates
int comparison = TalendDate.compareDate(date1, date2);

// Check the result of the comparison
if (comparison < 0) {
    System.out.println(date1 + " is before " + date2);
} else if (comparison == 0) {
    System.out.println(date1 + " is equal to " + date2);
} else {
    System.out.println(date1 + " is after " + date2);
}
```